# Naudio .net Using MP3

Tags: c#, .net

How can i play embedded resources using Naudio? Because the methods included in this library accept the string path to the file... and since im kind of a newbie I cannot edit those methods, I want to know if theres a way around?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Yes, i tried using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName), no that you ever help after someone responds ...

Comment: show us your code which demonstrates what you did

Answer (score 0):

`Mp3FileReader` has a constructor that takes a stream which you should be able to use. The stream does need to be seekable.